# How to add text to CIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cgimage, ciimage

I am working with the Photos framework and have created an app that will apply a filter to an image. Now instead of applying a filter, I want to add text on top of the image. This API provides me with a `CIImage` which I can use to create an output `CIImage`. I just do not know how to add text at a specific location to a `CIImage`. If I am correct, it would not be recommended to convert it to a `CGImage` and then add the text due to performance degradation.

How could one work with an existing `CIImage` to output that exact same `CIImage` (preserve original image quality) with text laid on top at a specific location?

```
//Get full image
let url = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
let orientation = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageOrientation
var inputImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: url)
inputImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingOrientation(orientation)

//TODO: REPLACE WITH TEXT OVERLAY
/*//Add filter
let filterName = "CISepiaTone"
let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName)
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let outputImage: CIImage = filter.outputImage*/

//Create editing output
let jpegData: NSData = self.jpegRepresentationOfImage(outputImage)
let adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: AdjustmentFormatIdentifier, formatVersion: "1.0", data: filterName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

let contentEditingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: contentEditingInput)
jpegData.writeToURL(contentEditingOutput.renderedContentURL, atomically: true)
contentEditingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData

PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: asset)
request.contentEditingOutput = contentEditingOutput
}, completionHandler: { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if !success {
        NSLog("Error saving image: %@", error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw the text in grayscale into a separate `CGImage`, convert the `CGImage` into a `CIImage` (via [`[+CIImage imageWithCGImage:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006665-BABEAECH)) and then use it as a mask, sending it and the original `CIImage` to the [`CIBlendWithMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask) filter.

Comment: Beautiful. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: any example in swift?

Answer (score 2):

As of last year, there is a new `CIFilter` available called [CIAttributedTextImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciattributedtextimagegenerator?language=objc). Here is an example of how I've used it, wrapped up in a utility class method:

```
+ (CIImage *)imageWithText:(NSString *)message color:(CIColor *)color scaleFactor:(CGFloat)scaleFactor
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : CFBridgingRelease(CGColorCreateSRGB(color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)),
    };
    NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message attributes:attributes];

    CIFilter<CIAttributedTextImageGenerator> *filter = [CIFilter attributedTextImageGeneratorFilter];
    filter.text = text;
    filter.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;

    CIImage *result = filter.outputImage;
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug that doesn't let you select a new color for a subsequent invocation of this filter. IOW, once you render this filter once, every subsequent render will produce text of the same color as the first render, regardless of the color you pass in.

At any rate, this will produce a `CIImage` that you can then overlay onto your `inputImage` like so:

```
CIImage *textImage = [YourUtilityClass imageWithText:@"Some text" color:[CIColor whiteColor] scaleFactor:1.0];
CIImage *outputImage = [textImage imageByCompositingOverImage:inputImage];
```

I don't have a lot of recent experience with Swift, but hopefully this Objective-C code is straightforward enough for you to get the idea.